# Required Field Validator issue validating TextBox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, uri, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a `TextBox` which i use to store a url to applied a `<asp:HyperLink>` control. What i want to do is fire off the `RequiredFieldValidator` when the `TextBox.Text` value is empty and the user clicks *save*. As far as i can tell, my logic is OK, but the validator isn't firing off?

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="frmRow">
        <div class="frmControls">  
            <asp:Label ID="lblLink" AssociatedControlID="txtImgUrl" runat="server" Text="Image URL"></asp:Label>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="imgUrlValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtImgUrl" ErrorMessage="Enter a Valid URL"  />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtImgUrl" runat="server" />  
        </div>
        <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the code to check a valid absolute URL which is inside my `btnSave` event:

```
Uri url;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtImgUrl.Text))
{
    txtImgUrl.Text = Uri.TryCreate(txtImgUrl.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url) ? url.AbsoluteUri : string.Empty;
}
```

Save button markup:

```
<br class="clearBoth" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save Case study" ImageUrl="~/Assets/Design/buttons/btn-update.gif" CssClass="btn fltr" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" />
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
```

Shouldn't the `RequiredFieldValidator` be fired off when `TryCreate` fails on a dodgy URL and `txtImgUrl.Text = ""`?

Is there something blatantly obvious that I'm missing here?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Your validator is working correctly, can you show us button code

Comment: Updated question to include save method

Comment: I was asking for save button in html as when txtImgUrl is empty the save trigger on server side will not fire. And your page will not be posted back.

Comment: Will post that too, one sec...

Comment: try add `ValidationGroup` attribute to your `textbox` and `button` or something which will starting validating method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check on button click

```
 if (Page.IsValid) 
         {
            lblOutput.Text = "Required field is filled!";
         }
         else 
         {
            lblOutput.Text = "Required field is empty!";
         }
```

In ASPX in the button add

```
CausesValidation="true"
```

Comment: I tried putting this inside my button click event around the final call to update the DB with the new case study but `Page.IsValid` always returns `true`.

Comment: You will probably need to call Page.Validate() before checking this as it needs to recheck

Comment: @Duane, put `CausesValidation=true` against your button in aspx page