# ASP.net CustomValidator - ClientValidationFunction to check value not blank and not initial value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have following code which validates the value of a textbox to make sure it's not blank but I also need to check that it does not equal the initial value of the textbox (defaultValue).

Here's what I have so far...

**Javascript:**

```
function textValidation(source, arguments)
   {
        if ( arguments.Value != "" ){ // && arguments.Value != arguments.defaultValue
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            $(source).parents("div").css({"background-color":"red"});
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
   }
```

**.net**

```
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Initial" Text="Initial" defaultValue="Initial" Width="120px" />                               

<asp:CustomValidator id="Initial_req"
     ControlToValidate="Initial"
     ClientValidationFunction="textValidation"
     ValidateEmptyText="true"
     runat="server"
     CssClass="errorAsterisk"
     Text="*" 
     ErrorMessage="Complete all correspondence fields" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do what you want using a CSS class to identify the TextBox and retrieve it with jQuery, allowing you to obtain the attribute `defaultValue`:

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" 
             ID="Initial" 
             Text="Initial" 
             defaultValue="Initial" 
             Width="120px" 
             ValidationGroup="Test" 
             CssClass="to-validate" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="Initial_req" 
   ControlToValidate="Initial" 
   ClientValidationFunction="textValidation"
   ValidateEmptyText="true" 
   runat="server" 
   CssClass="errorAsterisk" 
   Text="*" 
   ErrorMessage="Complete all correspondence fields"
   ValidationGroup="Test" />

<asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate" ValidationGroup="Test" />
```

Javascript:

```
function textValidation(source, arguments) {
     var initialValue = $(source).siblings(".to-validate:first").attr("defaultValue");

     if (arguments.Value != "" && arguments.Value != initialValue) { // && arguments.Value != arguments.defaultValue
         arguments.IsValid = true;
     } else {
         $(source).parents("div").css({ "background-color": "red" });
         arguments.IsValid = false;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RequiredFieldValidator` will prevent blanks as well as initial values.

Use attribute [`InitialValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx).

See [here](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/10/using-requiredfieldvalidator-attribute.html):

> Use it to prevent any value that you like being entered into a `TextBox`. The `TextBox` doesn't have to have that value embedded at the start - it just can't be submitted with that value.

Comment: This will require two `RequiredFieldValidators` - one to validate "Initial" and other to validate "".

Comment: This was my initial approach, but as you'll see from my code, I want to be able to change the background color of a parent element so needed to use the CustomValidator. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius - no, one validator will do both blank and initial

Answer (score 0):

1)You not pass source and  arguments parameters in your function  .

2) then call this syntax way for ClientValidationFunction="javascript:textValidation(param1,oaram2);return true;"

3)you can use required field validation in text box [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222800/required-field-validator-issue-validating-textbox-value)

4)or another way is (we dont use any parameter ) for [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1134282.aspx/1)