# ASPNET Custom Validtor Error Message is not displaying

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have aspnet application with custom validator using java script. I have to compare 2 dates in textboxes (txtbeginDate ,txtEndDate).
I wrote my java script as

```
Java Script:
function DateCompareClient(oSrc, args)
 {
    var begindt = new Date(document.getElementById('txtBeginDate').value);
    var endDt = new Date(document.getElementById('txtEndDate').value);
    if (begindt < endDt) {
        args.valid = true;
        return;
    }
    args.valid = false;
    return;
}
```

```
                                           <asp:CustomValidator
                                                    ID="Customvalidator3" runat="server"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" ErrorMessage="End Date must be later than Begin Date"
                                                    EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction="DateCompareClient" 
                                                    >*</asp:CustomValidator></td>
```

Now , script is runing fine, but its not displaying error message.
if condition is false , it should display error , which is not happening?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be accomplished without any javascript, called the [Compare Validator](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/compare-validator/)

```
 <asp:CompareValidator id="compareStartAndEndDates" 
                ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" 
                ControlToCompare="txtBeginDate" 
                Operator="LessThan"
                Text="End Date must be after Begin Date" 
                Type="Date"
                runat="server"/>
```

I suspect that your validator is never actually firing. Stick an `alert()` in your javascript to test that.

On your textboxes, you want to make sure they are set to `AutoPostBack="true"` so that when the user moves away from that field, the validator kicks in. You might also need `CausesValidation="true"`

Comment: Thanks for responding , its client requirement. They have this scripts VB script they want to migrate to Java script. Coming to Error...Java script is firing, everything is fine except displaying of the error message. The custom validator is expecting input as true or false. script is also throwing either true or false....but args is not accepted by custom control

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249848/asp-net-customvalidator-clientvalidationfunction-to-check-value-not-blank-and   Are you sure it's not `args.IsValid=true;` ?

Comment: Thanks its worked for its args.IsValid=true instead of args.valid=true...Thanks for your help.....